# Backbone stopListening

Tags: backbone.js

As I know the `view.remove()` function will call the `stopListening()` automatcially. However, the event `posts:open` cannot be unbind if the `this.collection.stopListening()` is not called. Please help What is missing? I think I miss understand something.

```
// posts.js - Collection
this.listenTo(App, 'posts:open', function() { console.log("hello world"); } );

// posts-item-view.js - ItemView
events: { "click #open", "this.open"},

open: function() {
    App.trigger('posts:open', this.model);
}

// posts-com-view.js - CompositeView
destroy: function() {
    //if (this.collection) {
    //  this.collection.stopListening();
    //}

    this.remove();
},
```

Comment: the remove method on views automatically calls stopListening, but you seem to be indicating that the listener is in your collection, not a view

Comment: you means the remove method call view.stopListening() didn't call view.collection.stopListening() ?

Comment: correct, this is just to remove any listeners from the view originally created by calling this.listenTo - check the annotated source: http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-136